# Mathematica delaunay overlap

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, computational-geometry

I have a set of points:

```
    Data2D = {{-4.432561, 11.687700000000001}, 
   {-3., 5.196152}, 
   {-6.25,10.825320000000001}, 
   {-5.3412805,11.256510000000002}, 
   {-3.9550406666666666,9.523850666666668}, 
   {-3.4775203333333335,7.360001333333334},
   {-4.083333333333333, 7.072541333333334}};
```

When I call PlanarGraphPlot[Data2D], there are an overlap betwent element (3,5,7) and (2,3,6).

here is the picture
"https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvVBQ.png"

And when I add

```
{-5.166666666666666, 8.948930666666667}, {-4.560853666666667,9.236390666666667}
```

to Data2D, Mathematica doesn't give any result!

Comment: You might also want to mention that you're using the ComputationalGeometry package and what version of Mathematica you're on.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I can replicate the result. I also get the following error while running PlanarGraphPlot[]:

> CompiledFunction::cflist: Nontensor object generated; proceeding with uncompiled evaluation.

The problem seems to be in the DelauneyTriangulation[] function, because I get the same error (and partial/no output) when running that on Data2D. Apparently, from what I can tell, the reason it fails is because a bunch of your points are too close to collinear. I tried the following, and it worked like a charm:

```
PlanarGraphPlot[Data2D + Table[ {Random[],Random[]}, {Length[Data2D]}]]
```

Of course, this is not what you want, and the Mathematica function should do things right without the snag. I would submit a bug report on this but I wouldn't hold my breath on it getting fixed soon. Until then it might just be easier to implement your own [triangulation algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation#Algorithms).